# CSS - Bevel navigation div

Tags: html, css

I need to bevel the white div as it shown on the picture. I´m really not an exprert at beveling divs in css, so I would like to ask for your solutions. Thanks.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crjN4.png)

Comment: do you mean the black part on the bottom or the shadow dropped below?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS gradients in order to create a beveled corner.
Here's an example, just change this to what angle/colours you like:
  `background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 80%, red 80%, red 100%); }`